# SciPy Documentations outdated?

Tags: python, scipy

On web page:

**scipy.stats.skew**

[image]
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.skew.html

But when I try it:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documentation is fine.  The function will return an ndarray when you pass an nd array and an axis argument.  Numpy's mean shows the same thing.

Comment: What do you mean? When I try `type(st.skew(np.array([2, 8, 0, 4, 1, 9, 9, 0])))`, it still returns a float.

Comment: @NoName pass it an array with several dimensions and see what it returns'

Comment: wow, if that's the case, they should've mention it somewhere. "Returns" should show all possible datatypes.

Comment: @NoName this has more to do with what numpy calls an array rather than what scipy returns.  Note `type(np.array(1))`.  What does that return?  If you have an issue, I would suggest you make a PR to scipy.